# Cake php configuração

Tags: cakephp

Configurei meu cake tudo certo, mas quando abro a página principal, o css dele não carrega, alguém pode me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

### Erro

Falta configurar o `mod_rewrite` do seu servidor apache

### Como configurar

Como é possível ver na [**documentação do cake php**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/pt/installation/advanced-installation.html#apache-e-mod-rewrite-e-htaccess) a configuração do `mod_rewrite` é feita da seguinte forma.

**Apache e mod_rewrite (e .htaccess)**

O CakePHP é desenvolvido para trabalhar com o mod_rewrite, mas percebemos que alguns usuários apanharam para fazer isto funcionar nos seus sistemas, então nós lhe daremos algumas dicas que você pode tentar fazer para rodar corretamente.

Aqui estão algumas coisas que você pode tentar fazer para rodar corretamente. Primeiro veja o seu httpd.conf (tenha certeza de estar editando o httpd.conf do sistema e não o de um usuário ou de um site específico).

Tenha certeza que a sobreposição do .htaccess está sendo permitida, ou seja, que o AllowOverride está configurado como All para o DocumentRoot. Você deve ver algo similar a isso:

```
# Cada diretório com o Apache tenha acesso pode ser configurado com
# relação aos quais serviços e recursos são permitidos e/ou
# desabilitados neste diretório (e seus subdiretórios).
#
# Primeiro, configuramos o o "padrão" para ter um conjunto muito
# restrito de recursos.
#
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Tenha certeza de estar carregando o mod_rewrite corretamente. Você deve ver algo como:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

Em muitos sistemas isso vem comentado por padrão (começando com um #), então você apenas precisa remover esses símbolos.

Depois de fazer as alterações, reinicie o Apache para ter certeza que as configurações estão aivas.

Verifique se os seus arquivos .htaccess estão nos diretórios corretos.

Isso pode acontecer durante a cópia, pois alguns sistemas operacionais tratam arquivos que começam com ‘.’ como oculto e, portanto, você não poderá vê-los copiar.

Tenha certeza que sua cópia do CakePHP é veio da seção de downloads do nosso site ou do nosso repositório GIT, e foi descompactada corretamente verificando os seus arquivos .htaccess.

No diretório raiz do Cake (precisa ser copiado para o seu DocumentRoot, este redireciona tudo para a sua aplicação):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

O diretório app do seu Cake (será copiado para o diretório principal da sua aplicação pelo bake):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Diretório webroot do Cake (será copiado para a raiz da sua aplicação web pelo bake):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Para muitos serviços de hospedagem (GoDaddy, 1and1), seu servidor web sendo servido a partir de um diretório de usuário que já utiliza o mod_rewrite. Se você está instalando o CakePHP dentro do diretório de um usuário (http://example.com/~username/cakephp/), ou qualquer outra estrutura de URL que já utiliza o mod_rewrite, você irá precisar adicionar instruções RewriteBase para os arquivos .htaccess do CakePHP (/.htaccess, /app/.htaccess, /app/webroot/.htaccess).

Isto pode ser adicionado à mesma seção da diretiva RewriteEngine, por exemplo, o arquivo .htaccess do seu webroot seria algo como:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /path/to/cake/app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Os detalhes dessa mudança vai depender de sua configuração, e pode incluir algumas coisas adicionais que não estão relacionadas ao Cake. Consulte a documentação online do Apache para mais informações.

Comment: Exatamente, faltou configurar o ".htaccess" do webroot, valeu amigo.

Comment: se puder marcar como correta eu agradeço